# pushViewController from another class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I want to push a view controller from my `FirstViewController` to load `BookDetailsViewController`. here's the setup I currently have.

```
// FirstViewController:(this is inside a uinavigationcontroller)

    -(IBAction)viewBookDetails:(id)sender
    {
      NSLog(@"woo");
      BookDetailsViewController *bdvc = [[BookDetailsViewController alloc] init];
      [self.navigationController pushViewController:bdvc animated:YES];
    }

    ==============================================================        

// BookScrollViewController: (where the button is located)

    [book1UIButton addTarget:self action:@selector(viewBookDetails:)   
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

     -(void)viewBookDetails:(id) sender
    {
      FirstViewController *fvc = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
      [fvc viewBookDetails:sender];
    }

    ============================================================== 

    //how BookScrollViewController is created
    BookScrollViewController *controller = [bookViewControllersArray  
    objectAtIndex:page];

    if ((NSNull *)controller == [NSNull null]) {
      NSString *bookTitle = @"ngee";
      controller = [[BookScrollViewController alloc]initWithBook:bookTitle  
      imageNamesArray:imgDataArray pageNumber:page totalResult:[newReleasesArray 
      count]];

      [bookViewControllersArray replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:controller];
      [controller release];
    }

    // add the controller's view to the scroll view
    if (nil == controller.view.superview) {
      CGRect frame = bookScroll.frame;
      frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
      frame.origin.y = 0;
      controller.view.frame = frame;
      [bookScroll addSubview:controller.view];
    }
```

when I tap the button in `BookScrollViewController` it calls the `IBAction` I have in `FirstViewController` coz it prints my nslog but it's not loading pushing the `BookDetailsViewController` to the navigation stack.

I tried assigning a button from `FirstViewController` to call the `IBAction` and it loads just fine. So, how can I successfully call the `IBAction` from `FirstViewController` using the button from `BookScrollViewController`?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you are assigning an action in the following way:

```
[book1UIButton addTarget:self action:@selector(viewBookDetails:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

You say that (current object: `self`) `BookScrollViewController *self` will respond to events `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` of `book1UIButton`. That means when user tap on button method `viewBookDetails` of object of class `BookScrollViewController` will be called.

As you mentioned in your question you have defined and implemented such method in `FirstViewController`.

Now you should

1. implement that method in `BookScrollViewController` that will push new controller onto navigation stack, or
2. set another object that will respond on that button event, that object can be of class `FirstViewController`, for example, `[book1UIButton addTarget:self.firstViewController action:@selector(viewBookDetails:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`

Comment: I created a property of FirstViewController in BookScrollViewController like this @property(nonatomic, retain)FirstViewController *firstViewController; and I do this in my viewDidLoad - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [book1UIButton addTarget:firstViewController action:@selector(viewBookDetails:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
.....
but is still won't load my BookDetailsViewController.

Comment: It is wrong. You are going in right way by creating such property. Now you need set it correctly: when you have created `BookDetailsViewController *bookController = [[BookDetailsViewController alloc] init];` in your `FirstViewController` you should set `bookController. firstViewController  = self;`

Comment: Im sorry I don't get this at all. :( the property I made is in BookScrollViewController, I also need to create another property of FirstViewController in BookDetailsViewController? I'm sorry for being noob. :)

Comment: Post the code where you are creating controller of class `BookScrollViewController `

Comment: I included the part I created BookScrollViewController. You see, BooksScollViewController will be added as a subView in FirstViewControlller.

Comment: Ok, now before `releasing` controller add this: `controller. firstViewController = self;`

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
FirstViewController *fvc = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
```

you obviously create a new instance of FirstViewController. That new instance is *not* in a UINavigationController, so you can't push a new viewController onto its navigationController property.

What you probably want to do is reference the *existing* instance of FirstViewController and call the method on it instead of creating a new instance of it.